# how to position divs with the same name next to each other and centered

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want the following two image to be displayed next to each other and centered

```
    <div class="newnew" align="center">
    <div class="gs-result gs-imageResult">
      <div class="gs-image-box">
      <img src="picture1" id="badge1"></img>
        <a class="gs-image">
          <img class="gs-image"/>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="gs-text-box">         
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gs-result gs-imageResult">
      <div class="gs-image-box">
      <img src="picture2.png" id="badge1"></img>
        <a class="gs-image">
          <img class="gs-image"/>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="gs-text-box">

      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried using float: `.gs-image-box{float:left;}`
That works, however then the pictures are not centered anymore. i ALSO tried inline-block & -table but didn't work. I think the problem is that the class names are the same for everyone. Does anyone have an idea how to solve that?
THanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me that inline-block does do what you want, but you should be calling it on the gs-result class elements instead:

```
.gs-result{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/o9s0h7j0/

Comment: WORKS ! GREAT THANK YOU! I'm trying for hours now !